# Single table view through two different NSFetchedResultsControllers with sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Good morning to everyone. I am using Swift 3.1.1, Xcode 8.3.2. I need to connect a single Table View to two different tables (entities) in Core Data through two different NSFetchedResultsControllers. I have created two NSFetchedResultsControllers, and even fetched data from table but I faced problem how to tell Table View that first controller should response for section one and second controller should be responsible for section two. 
I can show you the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tv: UITableView!

    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        ModelA.read { table1 in
            ModelB.read { table2 in
                if table1.isEmpty {
                    ModelA.save(recordToSave: [(a: 1, b: "a"), (a: 2, b: "b"), (a: 3, b: "c")]) {
                        ModelB.save(recordToSave: [(a: 4, b: 5.0, c: true), (a: 6, b: 7.0, c: false)]) {
                            self.tvReload()
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    self.tvReload()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var fetchedResultsControllerForModelA = CoreDataFunctions.fetchedResultsController
    var fetchedResultsControllerForModelB = CoreDataFunctions.fetchedResultsController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tvReload()
    }

    func modelOfTableA(indexPath: IndexPath) -> (forLabel1: String, forLabel2: String, forLabel3: String)? {
        if let fetchedResultsControllerForModelA = CoreDataFunctions.getNSManagedObjectForIndexPathOfTable(fetchedResultsController: fetchedResultsControllerForModelA, indexPath: indexPath) {
            if let model = ModelA.read(nsmanagedobject: fetchedResultsControllerForModelA) {
                return (forLabel1: "\(model.a)", forLabel2: model.b, forLabel3: "")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func modelOfTableB(indexPath: IndexPath) -> (forLabel1: String, forLabel2: String, forLabel3: String)? {
        if let fetchedResultsControllerForModelB = CoreDataFunctions.getNSManagedObjectForIndexPathOfTable(fetchedResultsController: fetchedResultsControllerForModelB, indexPath: indexPath) {
            if let model = ModelB.read(nsmanagedobject: fetchedResultsControllerForModelB) {
                return (forLabel1: "\(model.a)", forLabel2: "\(model.b)", forLabel3: "\(model.c)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func tvReload() {
        fetchedResultsControllerForModelA = CoreDataFunctions(tableName: .a).fetchedResultsController(keyForSort: ModelA.a.rawValue, searchParameters: nil)
        fetchedResultsControllerForModelB = CoreDataFunctions(tableName: .b).fetchedResultsController(keyForSort: ModelB.a.rawValue, searchParameters: nil)

        do {
            try fetchedResultsControllerForModelA?.performFetch()
            try fetchedResultsControllerForModelB?.performFetch()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tv.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let sections1 = fetchedResultsControllerForModelA?.sections {
            if let sections2 = fetchedResultsControllerForModelB?.sections {
                return sections1[section].numberOfObjects + sections2[section].numberOfObjects
            }
            return sections1[section].numberOfObjects
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if let modelOfTable = modelOfTableA(indexPath: indexPath) {
                cell.l1.text = modelOfTable.forLabel1
                cell.l2.text = modelOfTable.forLabel2
                cell.l3.text = modelOfTable.forLabel3
            }
        } else {
            if let modelOfTable = modelOfTableB(indexPath: indexPath) {
                cell.l1.text = modelOfTable.forLabel1
                cell.l2.text = modelOfTable.forLabel2
                cell.l3.text = modelOfTable.forLabel3
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

I could not find any tutorial on this theme, so I am asking question there. I do not want to use inheritance from single entity in Core Data, because, in real life it would be impossible.
Thank you for any help or advice!

Comment: why you are not individual array for each section?

Comment: I can use single array of tuples for both sections even without NSFetchedResultsControllers. I don't think, it is right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I downloaded your code, and there are a couple issues...

1) If you want your data to fill two sections in the table, the table must have two sections - currently, you are just returning 1, so use this (although you may want/need different handling based on data retrieved):

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if fetchedResultsControllerForModelA == nil || fetchedResultsControllerForModelB == nil {
        return 0
    }
    return 2
}
```

2) For number of rows in each section, your code was close but not quite right...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsControllerForModelA?.sections {
            return sections[0].numberOfObjects
        }
    } else {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsControllerForModelB?.sections {
            return sections[0].numberOfObjects
        }
    }

    return 0

}
```

3) For the actual cellForRowAtIndexPath data, again your code was close but you need to keep track of which data to get for each section...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if let modelOfTable = modelOfTableA(indexPath: indexPath) {
            cell.l1.text = modelOfTable.forLabel1
            cell.l2.text = modelOfTable.forLabel2
            cell.l3.text = modelOfTable.forLabel3
        }
    } else {
        // Each "Table data model" has only one section... since this is the 2nd table section, we need
        //  to change the section of the index path for our call to the data model
        let dataIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)
        if let modelOfTable = modelOfTableB(indexPath: dataIndexPath) {
            cell.l1.text = modelOfTable.forLabel1
            cell.l2.text = modelOfTable.forLabel2
            cell.l3.text = modelOfTable.forLabel3
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

That should get you on your way.

Comment: But, can you explain this part? let dataIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)

Comment: You have TWO data models - one for each Table Section. But each data model has only **ONE** data section. So, if you call `modelOfTableB()` and pass the table's index path for the first row in the second section, you will be asking for "section 1, row 0" ... which will fail, because "section 1" is the *second* section (zero-based indexing).

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now! Thank you one more time!